# PhantomJS (Poltergeist) does not display twitter bootstrap label element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I am trying to click an link with twitter bootstrap `label` class in capybara test, however, the element is not displayed. After I remove the `label` class, the element is displayed and clickable.

This observation is based on using capybara's `screenshot_and_open_image` method when debugging the problem. Any idea for this strange behaviour?

*(The page is rendered correctly in major browsers.)*

Comment: Does this `a` tag have an `href` attribute?

Comment: Yes it does. `<a class="label label-primary" href="/something">Something</a>`

Comment: What version of phantomjs are you using?

Comment: 1.9.8 on ubuntu x64. I am going to try v2. Thanks.

Comment: 1.9.8 implements a pretty old browser (Safari 5ish IIRC) so it could be some kind of css issue - 2.0.0 is a much more feature complete modern browser, but has issues with file upload -- 2.0.1 (unreleased as of now) fixes the file upload issues

Comment: @sh-ado-w, try increasing wait time!

Comment: PhantomJS version 2 solved the problem :) @TomWalpole, add it as an answer please.
But thanks for your comment Aravin too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS 1.9.8 implements a pretty old browser (Safari 5ish IIRC) so it could be some kind of css issue - 2.0.0 is a much more feature complete modern browser, but has issues with file upload -- 2.0.1 (unreleased as of now) fixes the file upload issues - Try using PhantomJS 2.0.0+